# Do the verbs "set" and "place" mean the same thing in these sentences?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I'm studying phrasal verbs from a book called **MacMillan Phrasal Verbs Plus**, and I'm studying the **"Down"** particle. In a page of the book, there is a diagram showing the various meanings of the "Down" particle and there are 2 sentences showing those apparently different meanings, shown in the image below, however it seems to me that those sentences have the same meaning, don't they?

**Do the two sentences have the same meaning?**

**Do the verbs "set" and "place" mean the same thing in those sentences?**

> Sentence 1: Placing something on a surface
>
> Sentence 2: Set something on a surface

[image: Placing vs setting]

====================================

**UPDATE #1**

Due to [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers)'s suggestion  the question has been moved [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/328794/do-the-verbs-set-and-place-mean-the-same-thing-in-these-sentences)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your response. I don't have more context for these verbs, only what has been provided for the diagram in the book.
I'm gonna publish my question in the site for English Learners.

Comment: _Set_ is the causative of _sit_, just as _raise_ is the causative of _rise_ and _lay_ is the causative of _lie_. All of these verbs refer to the orientation of the object. One _lays the fork on the table_, for instance, because forks are long, so they metaphorically _lie_. Similarly, one _sets the bottle_ on the table, rather than laying it, because it needs to be vertical, not horizontal. _Place_ is a general verb meaning to cause to be in a certain place, without reference to the status of the object.

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks. However, I didn't understand well the meaning of causative in your explanation. Could you provide another explanation or a link to a page that explain about "set" and its causative?

Comment: A causative verb is a verb that means 'to cause something to happen'. Usually that is some other verb. So _set_ means 'cause to sit', _lay_ means 'cause to lie', and _raise_ means 'cause to rise'. Just as _kill_ means 'cause to die'.

Comment: @JohnLawler so the sentence "set something on a surface" is equivalent to "to sit something on a surface"?

Comment: Yes, but that's nonstandard grammar. Some people use _sit_ as its own causative. Some people use _lay_ as its own inchoative. Usage varies from group to group; English is alive and therefore changing. It's certain to be spoken differently where you are than where I am, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular context involving an object being moved onto a surface, "set" and "place" mean *very close* to the same thing.

My reaction is that "set" implies a slightly higher level of care or attention than "place" implies, or that the process is a slightly neater or more controlled one. For example, if someone tells you to "set" a ball on a table, I would say that it implies that the ball should be placed on the table in such a way that it doesn't roll around after you release it. "Place" also implies a relatively attentive process (certainly in comparison to "put"), but perhaps not quite as much as "set." The difference is really minimal.

Of course, in other contexts, these verbs might not be so close. If we get rid of the surface, for example, things change. You might "place" your dirty laundry in a laundry bag (although even this is a bit of a formal way of saying it), but it would sound really weird to "set" your laundry in the bag. Perhaps the reason that this doesn't work is that, as noted above, "set" is a more careful process that probably gets the object into a neat and still position, as would usually occur on a surface.

Comment: But I have noticed that at least some Americans say _set_ where I would say _put_: for example "Father Paul set the lamp on the table", with no implication of greater care. This may be an old-fashioned or regional use, but I have encountered it more than once.

Comment: @ColinFine, yes, maybe so. I think "put" is by far the most common option in the U.S., too, with some old-timers more likely to use "set." But a lamp is kind of something that really should be put down with some attention, and normally is, so the distinction doesn't really come into play.

Comment: either way, I (BrE) would be unlikely to use "set" there at all.

Comment: Your 'reaction' is wrong - to place something denotes the more precise positioning of something on another thing. For example, a plane may 'set down' on a runway the moment its wheels touch the tarmac, but that is not its permanent placement. To set down simply means to put one thing on top of another. *Placing* something means to put it in a specific place. I think you may have got confused with 'setting a table', which does not mean putting the table somewhere specific, rather *placing* cutlery etc in specific places on the table.

Comment: @Astralbee, your plane analogy doesn't make sense. You're comparing something "setting down" on its own with somebody "setting" something on a surface. These apparently just work differently. I would think you would understand at least that. A plane "setting down" is not used in AmE and I would wonder if, when used in BrE, it does suggest a stoppage of movement. In AmE, if someone said that a flying animal or object "set down" somewhere, which would not be common at all, I actually *would* interpret it as suggesting a stoppage.